# Pass data to modal popup

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that opens a modal, it works without any issue but I'm now wanting to pass data from the button to a field within the modal.

HTML

```
<input type=button value='Add Background' id='myBtn2' data-toggle="modal" data-id="@book.Id" title="Add this item" class="open-AddBookDialog">

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close2">&times;</span>
<form action="includes/back.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <center>

    <h2><b>Background Information</b></h2>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="army_id" id="army_id" size="auto" value="">
    <font>Background Title:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="back_name" size="auto" value="">
<font>Background Info:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
<INPUT TYPE="textarea" NAME="commander" size="auto" value="">
<input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value=""/>
<font>
<b>STOP!</b><br>
Please check your information before pressing the submit button below. Looking over your information now will make sure editing later won't be necessary. Thank you.<BR>
<input type="hidden" name="FormSubmit" value="Yes">
<INPUT TYPE="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit Regiment"> &nbsp; <INPUT TYPE="reset" value="Reset Fields">
```

JS

```
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal2) {
modal2.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

I am hoping someone can advise me how to do that?

Comment: Can you make it working snippet? Also what do you want to pass to modal?

Comment: it's unsure if you did close your `</form>` tag and if all div opening/closing match and properly closed

Comment: I forgot to add the </form> to my code. I thought I had added a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to "pass data" to the modal -- it's part of the window, and you can use Javascript to affect it in the same way you do the button. For example, if you wanted to change the text in the modal, you could just do:

```
btn3.onclick = function() {
    modal2.textContent = 'different text!';
}
```

There's no real reason to encode data into the attributes of the modal, at least not unless you're planning something a more complicated than your example.

Also, there are some strange inconsistencies in your code -- why are your input elements sometimes written as `INPUT`, and sometimes as `input`? This doesn't have any bearing at all on how the page works, but it makes it a bit harder to read. Lastly, the `font` element is deprecated in HTML5 -- use CSS to set the font rules instead.

Comment: I'm wanting to pass a variable from an SQL query to a hidden field to be passed on submission of the form.

The reason for the inconsistencies and the deprecated font element is due to me combining code I wrote 7 years ago and what I've written recently.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on what exactly you want to do with the hidden field? I'm not entirely sure how SQL fits into your question.

Comment: The button passes an id to the hidden field which it then uses to link two tables. Normally I would like to a second page and pass the id in the URL using a get clause to put it in the hidden field in the form but I wanted to try something different.